# Contact Form validation error using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, validation

I'm doing contact form by passing value dynamically for all inputs fields.i have two forms on the same page using `id` i passed values. In js same code for these two forms. The problem is after passing correct value also it is showing an error and if I submit form1 then form2 also getting submitted. Here validations are not working I tried everything is correct what might be the problem.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  /* contact form tabs*/
  function button() {
    $('.demos-nav .iva-nav').click(function() {
      var btn = $(this).data('btn');
      $('.row').removeClass('current').css('display', 'none');
      $('.demos-nav .iva-nav').removeClass('current');

      $(this).addClass('current');
      $("#" + btn).addClass('current').css('display', 'block');

    })
  }
  button();
  /* name*/
  $("[class^='form_']").on('input', function() {
    var input = $(this);
    var is_name = input.val();
    if (is_name) {
      input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
    } else {
      input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
    }
  });

  /* E-mail */
  $("[class^='form_']").on('input', function() {
    var input = $(this);
    var regex = /^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/;
    var is_email = regex.test(input.val());
    if (is_email) {
      input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
    } else {
      input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
    }
  });

  /* Phone */
  $("[class^='form_']").on('input', function() {
    var input = $(this);
    var regex = /^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/;
    var is_phone = regex.test(input.val());
    if (is_phone) {
      input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
    } else {
      input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
    }
  });

  /* select People*/
  $("[class^='form_']").change(function() {
    var select = $(this);
    var selectOption = $("#contact_select option:selected").val();
    if (selectOption) {
      select.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
    } else {
      select.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
    }
  });

  /* select Time*/
  $("[class^='form_']").change(function() {
    var select = $(this);
    var selectTime = $("#contact_time option:selected").val();
    if (selectTime) {
      select.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
    } else {
      select.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
    }
  });

  /* Enquiry message*/
  $("[class^='form_']").keyup(function(event) {
    var input = $(this);
    var enquiry = $(this).val();
    if (enquiry) {
      input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
    } else {
      input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
    }
  });

  /* message*/
  $("[class^='form_']").keyup(function(event) {
    var input = $(this);
    var message = $(this).val();
    if (message) {
      input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
    } else {
      input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
    }
  });
  /* Submit */
  $("[id^='submit_']").click(function(event) {

    var form_data = $("[id^='form_']").serializeArray();

    var error_free = true;
    for (var input in form_data) {
      var element = $("#contact_" + form_data[input]['name']);
      var valid = element.hasClass("valid");
      var error_element = $("span", element.parent());

      if (!valid) {
        error_element.removeClass("error").addClass("error_show");
        error_free = false;
      } else {
        error_element.removeClass("error_show").addClass("error");
      }
    }
    if (!error_free) {
      return false;
    } else {
      $('.success_msg').fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
      $('input , textarea , select').val('').removeClass('valid');
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 1440px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.demos-nav {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 40px auto;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 1140px;
}

.success_msg {
  width: 350px;
  line-height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(213, 255, 187, 0.7);
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  z-index: 999;
  text-align: center;
}

.iva-nav {
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  transition: all 0.74s ease;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
}

.iva-nav span {
  transform: translateZ(8px);
  user-select: none;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 999;
}

.iva-nav:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(254, 180, 29, 0.3);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 225, 225, 0.4);
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 50;
}

.iva-nav:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(254, 180, 29, 0.3);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 225, 225, 0.4);
  transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 25;
}


/*.iva-nav:hover {
 transform: rotateX(-180deg) rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(180deg) ;
}*/

.iva-nav:hover:before {
  transform: rotate(225deg);
  background-color: rgba(254, 180, 29, 0.6);
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 225, 225, 0.1);
}

.iva-nav:hover:after {
  transform: rotate(133deg);
  background-color: rgba(254, 180, 29, 0.6);
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 225, 225, 0.1);
}

.fancy-heading-s1 {
  max-width: 1400px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding: 25px 0;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.fancy-heading-s2 {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 20px 0;
  color: #fff;
}

.fancy-title {
  display: block;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin: 20px 0;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.cfar-s1 .cfar-heading {
  text-align: center;
}

*:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.cfar {
  max-width: 1140px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.cfar-s1 {
  padding: 40px 100px;
  background-color: #313439;
}

.cfar-s1 .fancy-title span {
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.cfar-s1 .fancy-title span:after {
  content: " . ";
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: translateY(-15%);
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.cfar-s1 .fancy-title span:last-child:after {
  content: "";
  margin-right: 0;
}

.cfar-s1 .fancy-heading-s2 h2 {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.cfar-s1 .fancy-heading-s2 h2 span {
  color: #da4e5b;
}

.cfar-s1 form {
  padding: 30px 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.cfar .detail {
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px 0;
  flex-basis: 48%;
}

.cfar .detail input,
.detail textarea,
.detail select {
  display: block;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  padding: 5px 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: none;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.cfar option {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.cfar .detail textarea {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  resize: none;
}

.cfar .detail label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all 0.43s ease-in-out;
}

.cfar .detail .inputBar {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  transition: all 0.43s ease-in-out;
}

.cfar .detail input:focus:after,
.detail textarea:foucs:after,
.detail select:focus:after,
.cfar .detail .inputBar:focus:before,
.cfar .detail .inputBar:focus:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0;
  background: red;
  height: 2px;
}

.cfar .detail .inputBar:after {
  right: 50%;
}

.cfar .detail .inputBar:before {
  left: 50%;
}

.cfar .detail input:focus~label,
.cfar .detail input:valid~label,
.cfar .detail textarea:focus~label,
.cfar .detail textarea:valid~label {
  top: -20px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.cfar .detail input:focus~.inputBar:before,
.cfar .detail input:focus~.inputBar:after,
.cfar .detail textarea:focus~.inputBar:before,
.cfar .detail textarea:focus~.inputBar:after .cfar .detail select:focus~.inputBar:before,
.cfar .detail select:focus~.inputBar:after {
  width: 50%;
}

.cfar .detail .answer {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 114px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  left: 133px;
  position: inherit;
}


/* custom css*/

span.error {
  /*display: none;*/
  color: red;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px !important;
  right: 0;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.error_show {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  color: red;
}


/*input.invalid, 
textarea.invalid,
select.invalid {
 border: 2px solid red;
}*/

input:focus {
  outline-width: 0;
}

input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="demos-nav">
    <div class="iva-nav demo1" data-btn="demo1"><span>Demo 1</span></div>
    <div class="iva-nav demo2" data-btn="demo2"><span>Demo 2</span></div>

  </div>
  <!-- demos nav -->

  <div class="row current" id="demo1">
    <div class="cfar cfar-s1">

      <form id="form_info1" method="post" action="">
        <div class="detail">
          <input type="text" class="form_name1" id="contact_name1" name="name1" required autocomplete="off" />
          <span class="inputBar"></span>
          <!--inputBar-->
          <label for="contact_name1">Name</label>
          <span class="error">This field is required</span>
        </div>
        <!--detail-->
        <div class="detail">
          <input type="text" class="form_email1" id="contact_email1" name="email1" required autocomplete="off" />
          <span class="inputBar"></span>
          <!--inputBar-->

          <label for="contact_email1">Email</label>
          <span class="error">A valid email address is required</span>
        </div>
        <!--detail-->
        <div class="detail">
          <input type="number" class="form_phone1" id="contact_phone1" name="phone1" required autocomplete="off" />
          <span class="inputBar"></span>
          <!--inputBar-->
          <label for="contact_phone1">Phone Number</label>
          <span class="error">A valid Phone number is required</span>
        </div>
        <!--detail-->
        <div class="detail">
          <input type="text" class="form_enquiry1" id="contact_enquiry1" name="enquiry1" required autocomplete="off" />
          <span class="inputBar"></span>
          <!--inputBar-->
          <label for="contact_enquiry">I want to know about...</label>
          <span class="error">This field is required</span>
        </div>
        <!--detail-->
        <div class="detail message">
          <textarea type="text" class="form_message1" id="contact_message1" name="message1" required></textarea>
          <span class="inputBar"></span>
          <!--inputBar-->
          <label for="contact_message1">Type your Message here</label>
          <span class="error">This field is required</span>
        </div>
        <!--detail-->
        <div class="btn-container" id="submit_form1">
          <a href="#"><button type="submit" class="btn"> Submit</button></a>
        </div>

      </form>
      <div class="success_msg">
        <p>Form submitted Successfully</p>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- Contact Form style 1 -->
  </div>
  <!-- row  demo 1-->

  <div class="row" id="demo2">
    <div class="cfar cfar-s2">
      <div class="cfar-form">
        <h2 class="fancy-heading-s2"> Contact us </h2>
        <span class="fancy-title"> Reach out to us for any Inquiry</span>

        <form id="form_info2" method="post" action="">
          <div class="detail">
            <input type="text" class="form_name2" id="contact_name2" name="name2" required autocomplete="off" />
            <span class="inputBar"></span>
            <!--inputBar-->
            <label for="contact_name2">Name</label>
            <span class="error">This field is required</span>
          </div>
          <!--detail-->
          <div class="detail">
            <input type="text" class="form_email2" id="contact_email2" name="email2" required autocomplete="off" />
            <span class="inputBar"></s1pan><!--inputBar-->
         <label for="contact_email2">Email</label>
         <span class="error">A valid email address is required</span>
          </div>
          <!--detail-->
          <div class="detail">
            <input type="number" class="form_phone2" id="contact_phone2" name="phone2" required autocomplete="off" />
            <span class="inputBar"></span>
            <!--inputBar-->
            <label for="contact_phone2">Phone Number</label>
            <span class="error">A valid Phone number is required</span>
          </div>
          <!--detail-->
          <div class="detail message">
            <textarea type="text" class="form_message2" id="contact_message2" name="message2" required></textarea>
            <span class="inputBar"></span>
            <!--inputBar-->
            <label for="contact_message2">Type your Message here</label>
            <span class="error">This field is required</span>
          </div>
          <!--detail-->

          <div class="btn-container" id="submit_form2">
            <a href="#"><button type="submit" class="btn"> Submit</button></a>
          </div>
        </form>

      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Contact Form style 2 -->
  </div>
  <!-- row  demo 2-->
</div>
```

Comment: use jquery validation plugin

Comment: @whoami actually i dont want to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following changes in your code and design.
In html, change button tag to input tag,

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="demos-nav">
        <div class="iva-nav demo1" data-btn="demo1"><span>Demo 1</span></div>
        <div class="iva-nav demo2" data-btn="demo2"><span>Demo 2</span></div>

    </div>
    <!-- demos nav -->

    <div class="row current" id="demo1">
        <div class="cfar cfar-s1">

            <form id="form_info1" method="post" action="">
                <div class="detail">
                    <input type="text" class="form_name1" id="contact_name1" name="name1" required autocomplete="off" />
                    <span class="inputBar"></span>
                    <!--inputBar-->
                    <label for="contact_name1">Name</label>
                    <span class="error">This field is required</span>
                </div>
                <!--detail-->
                <div class="detail">
                    <input type="text" class="form_email1" id="contact_email1" name="email1" required autocomplete="off" />
                    <span class="inputBar"></span>
                    <!--inputBar-->

                    <label for="contact_email1">Email</label>
                    <span class="error">A valid email address is required</span>
                </div>
                <!--detail-->
                <div class="detail">
                    <input type="text" class="form_phone1" id="contact_phone1" name="phone1" required autocomplete="off" />
                    <span class="inputBar"></span>
                    <!--inputBar-->
                    <label for="contact_phone1">Phone Number</label>
                    <span class="error">A valid Phone number is required</span>
                </div>
                <!--detail-->
                <div class="detail">
                    <input type="text" class="form_enquiry1" id="contact_enquiry1" name="enquiry1" required autocomplete="off" />
                    <span class="inputBar"></span>
                    <!--inputBar-->
                    <label for="contact_enquiry">I want to know about...</label>
                    <span class="error">This field is required</span>
                </div>
                <!--detail-->
                <div class="detail message">
                    <textarea type="text" class="form_message1" id="contact_message1" name="message1" required></textarea>
                    <span class="inputBar"></span>
                    <!--inputBar-->
                    <label for="contact_message1">Type your Message here</label>
                    <span class="error">This field is required</span>
                </div>
                <!--detail-->
                <div class="btn-container" id="submit_form1">
                    <a href="#"><input type="button" class="btn" value="Submit"/></a>
                </div>

            </form>
            <div class="success_msg">
                <p>Form submitted Successfully</p>
            </div>

        </div>
        <!-- Contact Form style 1 -->
    </div>
    <!-- row  demo 1-->

    <div class="row" id="demo2">
        <div class="cfar cfar-s2">
            <div class="cfar-form">
                <h2 class="fancy-heading-s2"> Contact us </h2>
                <span class="fancy-title"> Reach out to us for any Inquiry</span>

                <form id="form_info2" method="post" action="">
                    <div class="detail">
                        <input type="text" class="form_name2" id="contact_name2" name="name2" required autocomplete="off" />
                        <span class="inputBar"></span>
                        <!--inputBar-->
                        <label for="contact_name2">Name</label>
                        <span class="error">This field is required</span>
                    </div>
                    <!--detail-->
                    <div class="detail">
                        <input type="text" class="form_email2" id="contact_email2" name="email2" required autocomplete="off" />
                        <span class="inputBar">
                            </s1pan><!--inputBar-->
                            <label for="contact_email2">Email</label>
                            <span class="error">A valid email address is required</span>
                    </div>
                    <!--detail-->
                    <div class="detail">
                        <input type="text" class="form_phone2" id="contact_phone2" name="phone2" required autocomplete="off" />
                        <span class="inputBar"></span>
                        <!--inputBar-->
                        <label for="contact_phone2">Phone Number</label>
                        <span class="error">A valid Phone number is required</span>
                    </div>
                    <!--detail-->
                    <div class="detail message">
                        <textarea type="text" class="form_message2" id="contact_message2" name="message2" required></textarea>
                        <span class="inputBar"></span>
                        <!--inputBar-->
                        <label for="contact_message2">Type your Message here</label>
                        <span class="error">This field is required</span>
                    </div>
                    <!--detail-->

                    <div class="btn-container" id="submit_form2">
                        <a href="#"><input type="button" class="btn" value="Submit"/></a>
                    </div>
                </form>

            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Contact Form style 2 -->
    </div>
    <!-- row  demo 2-->
</div>
```

The script is,

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

        /* contact form tabs*/
        function button() {
            $('.demos-nav .iva-nav').click(function () {
                var btn = $(this).data('btn');
                $('.row').removeClass('current').css('display', 'none');
                $('.demos-nav .iva-nav').removeClass('current');

                $(this).addClass('current');
                $("#" + btn).addClass('current').css('display', 'block');

            })
        }
        button();
        /* name*/
        $("[class^='form_name']").on('change', function () {
            var input = $(this);
            var is_name = input.val();
            if (is_name) {
                $(input).removeClass("invalid");
                $(input).addClass("valid");
            } else {
                $(input).removeClass("valid");
                $(input).addClass("invalid");
            }
        });

        /* E-mail */
        $("[class^='form_email']").on('change', function () {
            var input = $(this);
            var regex = /^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/;
            var is_email = regex.test(input.val());
            if (is_email) {
                input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
            } else {
                input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
            }
        });

        /* Phone */
        $("[class^='form_phone']").on('change', function () {
            var input = $(this);
            var regex = /^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/;
            var is_phone = regex.test(input.val());
            if (is_phone) {
                input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
            } else {
                input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
            }
        });

        /* Enquiry message*/
        $("[class^='form_enquiry']").keyup(function (event) {
            var input = $(this);
            var enquiry = $(this).val();
            if (enquiry) {
                input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
            } else {
                input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
            }
        });

        /* message*/
        $("[class^='form_message']").keyup(function (event) {
            var input = $(this);
            var message = $(this).val();
            if (message) {
                input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
            } else {
                input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
            }
        });
        /* Submit */
        $("[id^='submit_']").click(function (event) {

            var form_data = $(this).parent().serializeArray();

            var error_free = true;
            for (var input in form_data) {
                var element = $("#contact_" + form_data[input]['name']);
                var valid = element.hasClass("valid");
                var error_element = $("span", element.parent());

                if (!valid) {
                    error_element.removeClass("error").addClass("error_show");
                    error_free = false;
                } else {
                    error_element.removeClass("error_show").addClass("error");
                }
            }
            if (!error_free) {
                return false;
            } else {
                $('.success_msg').fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
                $('input , textarea , select').val('').removeClass('valid');
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: validations events not working I have multiple forms in the same page that's why I was taken `"[class^='form_']"` like this to all input fields. once check why validation is not working properly.

Comment: yes I tried your code. here ` $("[class^='form_name']")` your passing value directly then what about next form validation?

Comment: I am not using directly. In your first form, the class name is `form_name1` and in the second form, it is `form_name2`, but I used `form_name` only. So in both the cases, it will work

Comment: thanks. I have tried according to your code also but it is not working.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Given full working design and script. try that

Comment: thanks it's working this is what I'm trying to do.:)

Answer (score 0):

In the submit handler, you are referencing both the forms. which is why validations in both the forms are firing. Try getting the reference of the form to which the clicked submit button belongs to.

```
$("[id^='submit_']").click(function(event) {
   var form = $(this).closest("form");
   var form_data = form.serializeArray();
    //remaining code
```

Hope this gives you an idea.

Comment: @M Irshad Ul Haq what about validation is also not working.

Comment: Actually you are not binding events to elements correctly.

Comment: @M Irshad Ul Haq how should I do?

Comment: `$("[class^='form_name']").keypress( function() {
    var input = $(this);
    var is_name = input.val();
    if (is_name) {
      input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
    } else {
      input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
    }
  });`

Comment: you have to do it for other controls in similar fashion. do note that keypress event is only for textbox and textarea controls. for dropdowns, use `$('select').on('change', function() {  .... });`

Comment: @M Irshad Ul Haq thanks. But validation events not working. what might be the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try to use newest version of jQuery?? Like: [3.3.1](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js)

> updated

Try to change all your if statements for example:

```
 /* name*/
  $("[class^='form_']").on('input', function() {
    var input = $(this);
    var is_name = input.val();

    if (is_name === ' ') {
      input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
    } else {
      input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
    }
  });
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/ploutos27/pen/BxmKLZ)